Name of early 90's movie with boy travelling to other dimension with dog and friends
I am searching a movie that I saw when I was a kid. I vaguely remember the plot, but it was one of those low-budget films from the 90's (Or late 80's, I'm not pretty sure) but the story was something like this: 
A high-school boy has some object (I think it was a watch, but again, I'm not sure) and he could travel between dimensions (in space and time) to other places, he goes with his friends and also his dog, and the last scene shows him and his dog without friends in a jungle, so he says to his dog, wherever they are, they are going to be well.
Edit:
the movie is not A boy and His Dog (1975) because it appeared modern American culture (the boy has a 90s haircut that is oily, dark, semi-long, and split from the center; and he wears 90s clothes and trainers), it is similar to the Sliders series but it was more high-school like, and he eventually can't come back home, he's alone with his dog in a jungle. Sorry I cannot be more explicit.
